# Upgrade a built-in function: Nearest (mimic the behavior of V. 10.1 in previous versions)

Tags: built-in-symbols

For versions prior to 10.1 the following returns a error message

```
timedat = {1.1, 2, 3.3};
equalTime = {1, 2, 3};
Flatten@Nearest[timedat, equalTime]
```

> Nearest::dmtch: The dimension of {1.1,2,3.3} and {1,2,3} does not match. >>

A workaround is

```
Flatten[Nearest[timedat, #] & /@ equalTime]
(* {1.1, 2, 3.3}*)
```

However, I was thinking if there is a way to modify the default behavior of `Nearest`, for versions prior to 10.1, in order to achieve the better performance of the current version.

That is,

```
Flatten@Nearest[timedat, equalTime]
```

should return

```
{1.1, 2, 3.3}
```

Comment: `Flatten@With[{n = Nearest[#1]}, n /@ #2] &[timedat[[All, 1]], equalTime]`

Comment: `myNearest[l1_List, l2_List] := With[{n = Nearest@l1}, n /@ l2]` if you want it as a generalized function. You *could* unprotect `Nearest` and overload it, but generally, that's a seriously bad idea...

Comment: @ciao generalize that to pass through additional arguments and make it an answer.

Comment: @george2079: feel free to -  this strikes me as bordering on *RTM*...